# PCA in R: Error in svd(x, nu = 0, nv = k) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Tags: r, pca

My dataframe contains about 60 observations and 15 variables. They are mixture of continuous and binary data but  I've made sure all of the variables are numeric and do not have any NA values (used na.omit). I used is.finite, is.na to check for infinite/NA values. Using the function prcomp() on my dataframe tells me "Infinite or missing values in x". What might I be overlooking then? I am new to R, just started learning so i appreciate the help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwTWD.png)

Some of my columns are still characters and I am not sure how to change it, using gsub and then as.numeric still gives me an error.

```
    library(readxl)
>     Pca_for_R <- read_excel("~/Pca for R.xlsx")
      sapply(Pca_for_R, as.numeric)
      new <- gsub(",", "", Pca_for_R)
      Mypca <- prcomp(Pca_for_R, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
```

1. List item

Sample of my data:

> 

```
      CRT  GFA  MRT   VA Contast Myp Hyp eso exo VFV VFH
 [1,] 247 2.71 1283 0.63    2.50   0   0   1   0   0   0
 [2,] 226 2.06  442 1.00    1.50   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [3,] 251 2.16  420 1.00    1.25   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [4,] 202 3.02  282 0.80    1.25   0   1   0   0   0   0
 [5,] 252 2.17  640 0.50    1.50   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [6,] 260 2.25  857 0.40    1.50   0   1   0   0   1   0
 [7,] 255 2.51  736 0.63    1.20   0   1   1   0   0   0
 [8,] 242 1.90  353 1.00    1.20   0   0   1   0   0   0
 [9,] 206 1.90  292 0.80    1.20   1   0   0   0   0   0
[10,] 515 3.04  376 0.25    1.20   0   0   0   0   1   0
[11,] 222 2.13  424 0.80   10.00   0   1   0   0   1   0
[12,] 292 1.70  326 0.50    1.25   0   1   0   0   0   0
[13,] 207 2.55  427 1.00    2.50   0   1   0   0   0   0
[14,] 242 1.89  387 0.63    1.20   0   0   0   0   0   0
[15,] 205 1.86  341 1.00    2.50   0   0   0   1   0   0
[16,] 250 3.01  728 0.40    1.20   1   0   0   0   0   0
[17,] 269 3.51  410 0.50    6.00   1   0   0   0   0   1
[18,] 271 2.17  592 0.63    1.20   1   0   0   1   0   0
[19,] 264 1.52  235 0.63    1.20   0   0   0   0   0   1
[20,] 381 4.63  628 0.80    1.25   0   0   1   0   0   0
[21,] 342 3.35  422 0.30    2.50   0   0   1   0   0   0
[22,] 219 3.75  372 0.40    1.50   1   0   1   0   0   0
[23,] 306 3.35  564 0.40    3.00   0   0   0   0   0   0
[24,] 253 3.94  592 0.63    1.50   0   1   0   1   0   0
[25,] 268 2.13  387 1.00    1.25   0   0   0   0   0   0
[26,] 346 2.16  345 0.50    2.50   0   1   0   1   0   0
[27,] 289 1.79  370 0.50    1.50   0   0   0   0   0   0
[28,] 362 1.91  616 1.00    2.50   1   0   0   0   0   1
[29,] 321 3.65  791 0.50    5.00   0   0   0   0   0   0
[30,] 497 2.64  516 0.80    5.00   0   0   0   0   0   0
[31,] 291 2.52  900 1.00    5.00   0   0   0   0   0   0
[32,] 176 2.94  376 1.00    1.20   0   1   0   1   0   0
[33,] 192 2.00  336 0.32    2.00   0   1   0   0   0   0
[34,] 207 2.05  340 1.00    1.20   0   1   0   0   0   0
[35,] 331 2.05  480 0.80    1.20   0   1   0   0   0   0
[36,] 238 2.33  550 1.00    1.50   0   1   0   0   0   0
[37,] 205 4.32  554 0.63    5.00   0   1   0   0   0   0
[38,] 300 1.55  499 1.00    2.50   1   0   0   0   0   0
[39,] 374 2.92  687 1.00    5.00   0   0   0   0   0   0
[40,] 243 3.43  735 0.40    2.50   0   0   0   1   0   0
[41,] 221 2.39  489 0.50    1.25   0   0   0   0   0   0
[42,] 177 1.88  249 1.25    1.25   0   0   0   0   0   0
[43,] 377 3.35  581 0.50    5.00   0   0   0   0   0   0
[44,] 285 2.28  459 0.30   25.00   0   0   0   0   0   0
[45,] 230 2.17  438 1.00    1.80   0   1   0   0   0   0
[46,] 183 2.34  344 1.00    1.80   0   1   1   0   1   0
[47,] 245 1.63  418 0.50    1.25   0   1   1   0   0   0
[48,] 235 1.89  514 0.60    4.00   0   0   0   0   0   0
[49,] 179 2.89  525 0.30    4.00   1   0   1   0   0   0
[50,] 187 1.47  313 0.16    5.00   0   1   0   0   0   0
[51,] 243 2.48  331 0.63    3.00   1   0   0   0   1   0
[52,] 289 1.79  370 0.80    1.50   0   0   0   0   0   0
[53,] 287 2.80  569 0.60    6.00   0   1   0   1   0   0
[54,] 271 1.61  337 0.80    1.65   0   0   1   0   0   0
[55,] 198 1.70  429 0.80    1.25   0   0   0   0   0   0
[56,] 246 2.65  516 0.50    5.00   1   0   1   0   0   0
[57,] 318 2.16  746 0.25    8.00   0   0   0   1   0   0
[58,] 238 1.61  355 0.80    1.25   0   0   0   1   0   0
[59,] 268 2.13  387 0.32    1.50   0   0   0   0   0   1
[60,] 272 2.41  406 0.80    1.25   0   1   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: Do you have any multi-collinearity? That seems possible with so many columns with 0/1 values

Comment: Collinearity (even perfect collinearity) shouldn't stymie the `svd()` function; you would just end up with some singular values very close to zero.  I would call `debugonce(prcomp)` and then run your analysis.  This will let you jump into the function and investigate the objects that get created.  The `svd()` call is on line 19, so after `x` gets created on line 6, look at `x` to see if there are any `NA` or `Inf` values.

Comment: I notice that the second, fourth, and fifth columns of your data are left justified suggesting that they are stored as character data. This would definitely  be a problem. Pictures of your data are not very useful. Always provide your code and a sample of your data using `dput()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have added my code

Comment: @dcarlson, your right some of them are stored as character. I used gsub to remove the commas, it doesnt work. still shows the same error.